# Text Shown After Image in MWE But Not in Real Document

Tags: positioning

I want to show some text after an image. So following documentation, I made a MWE that works beautifully:

```
 \documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


At t = 90.5, $\delta_{1} = 0.131$, $\delta_{2}=0.872$, and $x[0] = 0.139$ we notice interesting behavior for the values of $x{t}$.
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, scale=0.5]{interesting.png}
  \caption{A change in sign of $\frac{dx}{dt}$}
  \label{fig: Modeled System}
\end{figure}

$\frac{dx}{dt}$ appears to undergo a sign change resulting in $x[t]$ losing value before regaining value to the point that at some point $t$, $x[t] > x[0]$
\end{document}
```

Then I tried it in my actual paper, and got this instead:[image: 1]][image]

Comment: figure is  float environment - and float environments can drift away if there is not enough place on the current page.

Comment: The _only_ thing the figure environment does is allow the content to be moved to help page breaking, by using `[ht]` you prevent float pages (`p`) so make it more likely that it drifts further away than it would otherwise have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike in the MWE, in your real document there is not enough space left on the page. If the text must come after the image, place a barrier to avoid it floating away:

```
 \documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}


At t = 90.5, $\delta_{1} = 0.131$, $\delta_{2}=0.872$, and $x[0] = 0.139$ we notice interesting behavior for the values of $x{t}$.
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, scale=0.5]{interesting.png}
  \caption{A change in sign of $\frac{dx}{dt}$}
  \label{fig: Modeled System}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier

$\frac{dx}{dt}$ appears to undergo a sign change resulting in $x[t]$ losing value before regaining value to the point that at some point $t$, $x[t] > x[0]$
\end{document}
```